# Best Way To Structure Object for Idle Game

Tags: javascript, html

I have a quick idle game I made in JS/HTML5 that uses an object to store information about what upgrades the player has.

```
var buttons = {

    //Button Key : [Name, Button Count, Initial Cost, Effect (how
    //much money to add per click/sec), Cost Exponent, Effect to
    //add on next upgrade]

    "upgradeClick" : ["Upgrade!", 0, 0.50, 0.01, 10, 0.01],
    "upgradeAuto" : ["Automate!", 0, 1.00, 0.00, 50, 0.01],
    "buyCompany" : ["Start A Company!", 0, 500.00]
}

for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(buttons).length; i++) (function(i) {
    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerHTML = buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][0] + "(" + buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][1] + ")<br>" + buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][2].toFixed(2);;
    newButton.id = Object.keys(buttons)[i];
    newButton.zIndex = 3;
    newButton.onclick = function() {
        if(d >= buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][2]) {
            d -= buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][2];
            buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][1] += 1;
            buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][2] = 0.5 * Math.pow(buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][4], buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][1]);
            buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][3] += buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][5];
            document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = buttons[this.id][0] + "(" + buttons[this.id][1] + ")<br>" + buttons[this.id][2].toFixed(2);;
            if(buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][1] % 5 == 0) {
                buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][3] += buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]][1] * 10;
            }
        }
    };
    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
})(i);
```

Is this the best way to store my buttons' information and retrieve it? Does it affect the speed/performance of my program to do it this way?

Comment: Do you have any performance problems with this? No? Then why are you asking about that?

Comment: And you should definetly clean up your code. `buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]]` should be cached!

Comment: @JonasW. By caching do you mean storing the variables, e.g. with local storage?

Comment: In a variable should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would structure your data into objects, and try to make use of variables to represent each button, rather than digging through `buttons[Object.keys(buttons)[i]]`.... to get at each property.  I didn't completely redo your code but here is a sample of how I would structure it.  I had to guess at what the values in the arrays were based on my awesome (lol) knowledge of idler games.  Using forEach instead of a for loop gives you a nice closure around the values you loop over so you don't need an IIFE.

```
var buttons = [{
    name: "upgradeClick",
    text: "Upgrade!",
    qty: 0,
    price: 0.50,
    multiplier: 10,
    priceAdd: 0.01
},{
    name: "upgradeAuto",
    text: ... (etc)
}];

buttons.forEach(function (btn, i) {
    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerHTML = btn.text + "(" + btn.qty + ")<br>" + btn.price.toFixed(2);
    newButton.id = btn.name;
    newButton.style.zIndex = 3;

    newButton.onclick = function () {
        if (d >= btn.price) {
            d -= btn.price;
            btn.qty++;

            btn.price = 0.5 * Math.pow(btn.multiplier, btn.qty);
            // etc
        }

    };

});
```